# How do I use starts-with with an attribute value?

Tags: xml, xpath

My xml look a bit like this ...

```
<DataItems>
  <DataItem name="Order Number" type="string">ABC1234</DataItem>
  <DataItem name="Customer Id" type="integer">667744</DataItem>
  <DataItem name="Customer Name" type="string">Ronnie Pickering</DataItem>
</DataItems>
```

I'm trying to use XPath 1.0 to return a boolean based on whether the Order Number start with a certain string - "ABC"

I can't figure it out at all.  Help, please.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
//DataItem[@name='Order Number' and starts-with(., 'ABC')]
```

will return all `DataItem` elements whose name is `'Order Number'` and whose string value starts with `'ABC'`.

Comment: That's great, thanks.  I've added a string-length() > 0  to it to give me a boolean.  Regards,

Comment: @MichaelVincent:  Not sure what you're shooting for with `string-length() > 0`, but if it's specifically a boolean you're looking for, you could wrap the above XPath in `boolean()`.

Comment: your answer returns a string - if I wrap that in boolean() what does it test for for true?  A non-empty string?  Or?  Anyway, that's what I was shooting for.  Regards,

Comment: No, my answer returns a nodeset in XPath 1.0 and a sequence in XPath 2.0, both of elements.  Wrapping it in `boolean()` will return false if empty, true otherwise.  If you're seeing the result as a string, then it is being passed through an external function, perhaps in the hosting language or calling system, that is turning it into a string.