# XPath based on named field value

Tags: xml, xpath

What XPath query should I do to retrieve all `property prop_id and prop_name` fields where the `property` contains a field  `<Field name="prop_label">resource_workskills</Field>`
In this sample, it should just load:

```
<Field name="prop_id">100</Field>
<Field name="prop_name">Work Skills</Field>
```

Sample data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
  <property>
    <Field name="prop_id">100</Field>
    <Field name="prop_label">resource_workskills</Field>
    <Field name="prop_entity_type">3</Field>
    <Field name="prop_name">Work Skills</Field>
    <Field name="Property ID">100</Field>
    <Field name="Property Language">1</Field>
    <Field name="Text Entry Identifier">0</Field>
  </property>
  <property>
    <Field name="prop_id">101</Field>
    <Field name="prop_label">resource_capacity_categories</Field>
    <Field name="prop_entity_type">3</Field>
    <Field name="prop_name">Capacity Categories</Field>
    <Field name="Property ID">101</Field>
    <Field name="Property Language">1</Field>
    <Field name="Text Entry Identifier">0</Field>
  </property>
</properties>
```

I do not know how to work with the value of a named field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
/properties/property[Field[@name="prop_label" and .="resource_workskills"]]
           /Field[@name='prop_id' or @name='prop_name']
```

will select all `Field` elements with `prop_id` or `prop_name` `@name` attribute values that are children of a `property` element that has a child `Field` element with a `prop_label` `@name` attribute value and a string value of `"resource_workskills"`:

```
<Field name="prop_id">100</Field>
<Field name="prop_name">Work Skills</Field>
```

as requested.

---

> This is great @kjhughes Thanks! What if I want to use a wildcard in the conditional, such as .="resource_*" so I match all starting by resource_

**See:** [`starts-with()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47334358/290085)

**See also:** [`contains()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39650007/290085) and [`ends-with()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40934644/290085)

Comment: This is great @kjhughes Thanks! What if I want to use a wildcard in the conditional, such as .="resource_*" so I match all starting by resource_ ?